# When should I use HttpDelete or HttpPut in an asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-put, http-delete

I use always HttpGet or HttpPost even when my action is executing a delete method on the database.

For what should I use then HttpDelete/HttpPut ?

Comment: You really can google it. Answering your question: you can always use post for data changing. There isn't a real need to use Put and Delete. most applications don't use them.

Comment: A word of advice: on a public web where the search spiders can reach - every Get is triggered while Post is not.  So if you can send a Get request to manipulate data be careful of how visible the link is.  FWIW

Comment: http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2011/10/using_http_methods_in_rest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you build an [OData](http://www.odata.org/) service.

**HTTP DELETE** - Deletes the entity data that the specified resource represents. A payload is not present in the request or response messages.

**HTTP PUT** - Replaces existing entity data at the requested resource with new data that is supplied in the payload of the request message. ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728282%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

There's [a presentation with Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ODataBasicsAtTheAZGroupsDayOfNETWithScottGu.aspx) that might be interesting. (I haven't seen it yet.)

There's also [a couple of lectures on pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses#odata) on OData if you have a subscription there.

Answer (score 16):

Web browsers only support GET and POST, so if you are building a web site, there is no need for PUT or DELETE. If you are building a RESTful api, though, PUT and DELETE are the way to go if you want your users to be able to put and/or delete stuff.

EDIT: It seems browsers do support DELETE and PUT in their implementations of XMLHttpRequest. Hence you can use them in ajax requests. Html forms, though, do not support them.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have understood about the use of `DELETE` request but `PUT` is a little different thing.

If I'm creating a new resource in the server and if the URI through which it can be accessed is decided by me then I'll go for `PUT`. In most of the cases the URI is decided by the server and hence `POST` go for creation and `PUT` usually for update.

Final thing is, like `GET` both `DELETE` and `PUT` are idempotent, means how many times the client send the requests serially the state of the server should be changed to same as in the first request.