# How make endpoints with different http methods in asp.net (.net framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a delete user route, but i can't get it to work.
Everything I find online is for `.NET CORE`.
I use `ASP.NET MVC`. So I ran `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` in `RouteConfig.cs`.
I than create a controller extending `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`. (Everything comes from the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace).

And I have the following method:

```
[HttpDelete, Route("user/{id:long}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Destroy(long id)
{
    IAccountService accountService = new AccountService();

    bool success = await accountService.Delete(id);

    return Json(new AuthenticateDto());
}
```

Rearranging the attributes doesn't work (I'm new to attributes so idk if it even helps)
When I try to visit the url i receive a 404.

Anyone has a clue, why it does not work?

Comment: How do you test it? Webbrowsers only support [*get* and *post*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888727/2441442). What happens, when you replace `[HttpDelete, Route("user/{id:long}")]` whith `[HttPost, Route("user/{id:long}")]` and call `/user/42`?

Comment: I used postman to test it and used the folowing url: https://localhost:44378/user/5

Comment: And did you selected delete in Postman?

Comment: yes, and If I change it with HttpPost it works just fine if I select Post

Comment: Do you have by chance a [route http contriant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19735430/2441442)?

Comment: Also have look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16241628/2441442

Comment: I do not know of contraints but i'm using attribute routes, not conventional routes ;-;.

Comment: I took a look at stackoverflow.com/a/16241628/2441442 and it did not fix it unfortunatly

Comment: okay, then I am out of ideas... Have an upvote ;)

Comment: I just checked with an ASp.Net MVC project - and the HttpDelete simply works out of the box - I am using Autofac as the container and registering controllers with it - but don't see why the default container shouldn't work. Are your other HTTP methods working with exactly the same route definitions ? I see that your route is starting with "User..." - typical route definitions follow the convention: {controller}/{action}/{id}  -- double check your route..

Comment: Speaking of routes, you registered [`routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38103475/2441442), didn't you?

Comment: you could try adding swagger and check if it works from the swagger UI ( Swashbuckle.Core )...

Comment: Yes I registered the ‘routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()’, And the routes are correct get and post works just fine, but delete doesnt

Comment: Try adding "[FromUri]" explicitly .. like so:
public async Task<ActionResult> Destroy([FromUri]  long id)

Comment: It works by adding [System.Web.Http.FromUri] explicitly, Thank you.